# Video streaming issue in Janus WebRTC Gateway for RTSP streaming source(For janus_streaming plugin)

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, rtsp, sdp, janus-gateway

I have installed Janus WebRTC Gateway on Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS, and deployed  web samples on apache2 http server.
I am trying existing Streaming demo sample which come with Janus gateway.
I have enabled(By default it is disabled) rtsp streaming support in 'janus.plugin.streaming.cfg' config file by below settings.

RTSP stream is generated using Live555 proxy server API, it works properly on VLC player.

```
[rtsp-test]
type = rtsp
id = 99
description = RTSP Test
audio = no
video = yes
url=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/mystream
```

Now I am getting one more channel(option in dropdown) in Streaming demo page i.e. 'RTSP Test(live)'. When I will click on `Watch or Listen` button, below error occurred on console and showing waiting symbol:

On Chrome:

> Failed to parse SessionDescription. Expect line: v=

On Firefox:

> InvalidParameterError: Empty or null SDP provided to
>   setRemoteDescription

Please help me to resolve this issue or suggest me any idea/code changes to play rtsp to WebRTC stream using Janus Gateway.

Comment: Could you add parts of the janus log ? Perhaps it reports some error ?